# cannot access home wireless in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10

Since i upgraded to 14.10 my home wifi doesn't show up in the list of available networks.
I can connect to the wifi by phone, or other computers, but not my laptop. (btw: samsung RV520)
I have tryed to allow my mac address in the router cfg, and it finally showed up on the list of networks, but didn't connect to it ...
I don't know how, why, but may this be a driver issue? I can connect to every other wireless networks, just not mine ... 
Thank you ...

Comment: It seems you have a Broadcom chip. Please open a terminal and run the command `lspci -nn | grep Wireless` to confirm this. If this is the case, proceed with the answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/75166

Comment: lspci returned :
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently after upgrading to ubuntu14.10, it doesn't recognize channels up to 12, i modified channel to 3, and now it works!

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you successfully connect to other networks it's more likely to be your home router problem. The easiest solution is to reset your home router, if it's not a problem for you. Did you try just simply reboot your router? (I mean to disconnect it from rossete, wait for a couple of minutes and then plug it in again)

Comment: actually, i did not try that ... it's no problem, just wanted to know what could be the source of this problem ... i'm thinking that it's a router problem too, but no other computer has the same problem, and it was just my laptop after the upgrade ... may it be a problem with networking hardware?
#i'll try that too, if it doesn't work i post it again ...

Comment: It's very unlikely to be hardware or driver problem with your laptop

Comment: i think it is a hardware problem , no other computer has this problem, so router is not guilty, but i can connect to other networks + cable so it isn't my network card...
but if it isn't any of these, then what is? :/

Comment: Let's judge logically: if other devices can freely connect to your  Wi-Fi while your laptop can freely connect to other Wi-Fi networks except yours, so it's the matter of communication of exactly your laptop with exactly your Wi-Fi network. In such a case if your laptop finds your Wi-Fi try to "forget" network, check whether you've entered password correctly and finally try to reboot both your laptop and router. If all this fails to solve the problem, then it's the only option to try to reset your router. Again, hardware problem with your laptop is very unlikely.

Comment: yes, i tried to "forget" my network, and after the mac thing, it showed up, asked for pw, i entered and it just stayed there "thinking" and after a minute or so it connected to other wifi ...

Comment: Well, I've done with possible solutions but still quite sure that router reset should help)